# How to somewhat override a jQuery function after an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search-box

So I've got a page with a search box, a check-mark, and a loading spinner.  When the user focuses on the search box, spinner fades in.  User un-focuses on search box, spinner fades out.  I have a function to toggle the check-mark after the user presses enter in the search box, however, i would like the check-mark to stay visible forever.  As of now, when the user presses enter, it toggles the checkmark and shortly fades out because the unfocus function is called automatically.

Toggle checkmark function:

```
$('#searchText').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        var val = $('#searchText').val();
        $('.circle-loader').toggleClass('load-complete');
        $('.checkmark').toggle();

        alert(val);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Fade in and out function:

```
$(function () {
    $('#searchText').focusin(function () {
        $('#check').fadeIn();

    }).focusout(function () {
        $('#check').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

How can i override the fade in and out function (or rewrite this perhaps) to stop when the user presses enter in the search box?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery `.stop` method.  When `.stop()` is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped. If, for instance, an element is being hidden with `.slideUp()` when `.stop()` is called, the element will now still be displayed, but will be a fraction of its previous height. Callback functions are not called.

https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with a boolean to indicate if a search has been performed.  See below as an example.  Without knowing the structure of your code I made it global but that could be changed to check a particular object instead.

Toggle checkmark function:

```
var searchPerformed = false;
$('#searchText').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        searchPerformed = true;
        var val = $('#searchText').val();
        $('.circle-loader').toggleClass('load-complete');
        $('.checkmark').toggle();

        alert(val);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Fade in and out function:

```
$(function () {
    $('#searchText').focusin(function () {
        $('#check').fadeIn();

    }).focusout(function () {
        if (!searchPerformed)
            $('#check').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with

```
  $('#searchText').unbind("focusin");
  $('#searchText').unbind("focusout");
```

in the toggle check-mark function.
Thanks for alternate methods as well everyone, will be handy in the future.